# Run a script when connected to a network

Tags: networking, bash, 20.04

I am rather new to Linux, running ubuntu 20.04. I try to get a python-script running when I connect to a network (doesn't matter if it is LAN or wireless).

To test I have `test.sh` containing

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$IFACE" = "wlan0" ]; then
    echo "test">>out.txt
fi
```

I have tried placing it in `/etc/network/if-up.d` (made it executable), but that does not seem to work. I then tried placing it in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` but that does not seem to work either. I have tried switching network and just turning it off/on.

Comment: Your test script contains an "if" command, so it's possible that the condition is false, therefore the script does nothing. Make the script just write something (unconditionally) to a file `/tmp/out.txt` (use absolute pathname, because you don't know in which directory `out.txt` that is in your script may be located). Also writing to `/tmp` ensures there will be no permission issues, because any user is allowed to write there. If this succeeds, then the problem is in your script. If it doesn't succeed, this means your script is not run at all, and you need to look elsewhere for the cause.

Comment: I should have clarified that ; I tried without the "if" statement at first, and that does not run. Ill try writing to temp and check

Comment: Thanks for the `tmp` suggestion - it made it much more easy to debug.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work I placed it in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` and re-wrote it as

```bsh
!#/bin/bash
if [ "$2" = "up" ]; then #not "$IFACE = wlan0"
    echo "hello world!">>/tmp/out.txt
fi
```

I tried placing it in `/etc/network/is-up.d` (and modify it) but it would not work

Comment: this gets executed twice after boot for some reason